# UIWebOverflowScrollView causing crash in ads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, wkwebview

Has someone seen such a crash before? Does this occur due to UIWebView & is fixed in WkWebView?

View has lost track of its superview, most likely through unsupported use of CALayer API on the view's layer. If this isn't a crash yet, it will be in the near future. Problem view: ; layer = ; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {320, 7732}> Expected parent: ; layer = > Break on UIViewReportBrokenSuperviewChain to debug.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the reason is **-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch** property in the ad. If you remove this CSS property -- it should work.